Trying to alter YouTube playback speed
let isSpacebarHeld = false;

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.code === 'Space' && !isSpacebarHeld) {
        isSpacebarHeld = true;
        const video = document.querySelector('video');
        if (video) {
            const currentSpeed = getCurrentPlaybackRate();
            if (!video.dataset.originalSpeed) {
                video.dataset.originalSpeed = currentSpeed;
            }
            video.playbackRate = 4.0;
        }
    }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    if (event.code === 'Space') {
        isSpacebarHeld = false;
        const video = document.querySelector('video');
        if (video) {
            const originalSpeed = parseFloat(video.dataset.originalSpeed) || 2.0;
            video.playbackRate = originalSpeed;
            video.dataset.originalSpeed = '';
        }
    }
});

I want to paste this in the console for YouTube. I want the YouTube video playback to be at 4x speed whenever I press and hold my spacebar and get back at the selected speed when I release it. But it's making it 16x.

FYI: Holding space already sets the playback-speed to 2x (by default) - This could be part of the issue

Hi, @KushagraDwivedi video.dataset returning value as:  'DOMStringMap {originalSpeed: ''}'.

what is function getCurrentPlaybackRate() ? is it current video.playbackRate value ? @KushagraDwivedi

what is your default/original playback speed ? it that 1 or 2. I don't understand about your line:  const originalSpeed = parseFloat(video.dataset.originalSpeed) || 2.0; @KushagraDwivedi

So, according to my understand you want get 4x playback rate during continuous pressing of spacebar. Otherwise it should return to normal playback rate, which is 1 by default.
Please try the follow:
let isSpacebarHeld = false;

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
     console.log('keydown');
    if (event.code === 'Space' && !isSpacebarHeld) {
         console.log('keydown | space ---- continuous press');
        isSpacebarHeld = true;
        const video = document.querySelector('video');
        if (video) {
            const currentSpeed = video.playbackRate;
            console.log('currentSpeed', currentSpeed);
            if (currentSpeed === 1) {
                video.playbackRate = 4;
            }
            console.log('video.playbackRate', video.playbackRate);
        }
    }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
     console.log('keyup');
    if (event.code === 'Space') {
        console.log('keyup | space');
        isSpacebarHeld = false;
        const video = document.querySelector('video');
        if (video) {
            console.log('keyup originalSpeed', video.dataset.originalSpeed, ' dataset: ', video.dataset);
            const originalSpeed = (video.playbackRate || 1);
            if (originalSpeed !== 1) {
                video.playbackRate = 1;
            }
            console.log('video.playbackRate', video.playbackRate);
        }
    }
});

